# Views based on groups and exists across tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sqlplus

I have two tables:

T1

```
Col1    Col2
A       1
A       2
A       2
B       2
C       3
D       4
D       4
```

T2

```
Col1    Col2
A       2
B       2
C       4
```

I wish to create two views based on the following:

Where Col1 and Col2 from t2 exists in t1 a single time

Where Col1 and Col2 from t2 exists in t1 more than once

Expected output for this would be

view 1

```
Col1    Col2
B       2
```

View 2

```
Col1    Col2
A       2
```

How can I go about achieving this?

Table scripts:

```
create table t1 (col1 varchar2(1), col2 varchar2(2));
create table t2 (col1 varchar2(1), col2 varchar2(2));
insert into t1 values ('A',1);
insert into t1 values ('A',2);
insert into t1 values ('A',2);
insert into t1 values ('B',2);
insert into t1 values ('C',3);
insert into t1 values ('D',4);
insert into t1 values ('D',4);
insert into t2 values ('A',2);
insert into t2 values ('B',2);
insert into t2 values ('C',4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join `t2` on an aggregate query from `t2` that counts the number of `col1` occurrences:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT t2.*
FROM   t2
JOIN   (SELECT   col1, col2
        FROM     t1
        GROUP BY col1
        HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1) c ON t2.col1 = c.col1 AND t2.col2 = c.col2;

CREATE VIEW view2 AS
SELECT t2.*
FROM   t2
JOIN   (SELECT   col1, col2
        FROM     t1
        GROUP BY col1
        HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1) c ON t2.col1 = c.col1 AND t2.col2 = c.col2;
```

Comment: The output for view 1 is  C 4
B 2 .... I don't want the C 4 record (It exists once in T2, however isn't in T1 so shouldn't be visible)

Comment: @bobdylan The C record exists in T1 according to the insert scripts you provided, so by that logic it should exist in view1.

Comment: C4 is not in T1, but is in T2.

Comment: @bobdylan Oh, now I see it - you meant that the exact [col1,col2] combination should be evaluated in both tables. Mea culpa. See my edited answer.